# Giving ranges on my new job description (promotion)

Tags: salary, negotiation, canada

I have been offered a promotion at my current company. My boss has asked me to write a job description for this newly created position within a newly created department.

When asking about a base pay increase, my new boss said that I would be receiving an increase in pay due to an increase in responsibilities but the exact number would be decided by HR after a review of industry standards for this position and the job description.

I have 3 years experience in my current field. Is it best to give an experience range of 3-5 years experience as that would likely result in a more favorable (experienced) position that I am compared to online when determining salary?

The position change would be from an entry level position to a mid-level management position.

Comment: So, you have 3 y experience, but are planning on saying you have 3-5 years? Do you mention this range to HR somehow? Do they verify it somehow (what if you say you have 4-5)?

Comment: Can't HR just know or check on their own that range? I mean, surely they have your CV or resume, so that info could be taken from there. It's better to say the truth on CV and resume stuff (in all stuff actually)

Comment: "Write a job description" could easily mean "describe the responsibilities" rather than anything about experience. What do you mean by "give an experience range"? What exactly have you been asked to do?

Comment: I hate experience time ranges, they don't show how much you know about something. If the responsibilities/skills/knowledge needed are well described they are not necessary

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I see, so basically this new role is being defined here, but is defined by the one that will surely fill it. Seems that OP has quite some freedom there to define that role.

Comment: @DarkCygnus - Writing the description of their own position, in the required experience area, the author is suggesting that writing "requires 3 - 5 years of experience" instead of a number that puts OP in the middle or high end of the required range. Sounds reasonable, since they didn't offer the expanded responsibilities until OP got to three years, and rewriting the position probably means OP will be continuing in this role for a while. They didn't think OP could do it before, which makes the 3 yrs the lower end. HR then takes the description and scores it for job's pay range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have 3 years experience in my current field, is it best to give an
>   experience range of 3-5 years experience as that would likely result
>   in a more favorable (experienced) position that I am compared to
>   online when determining salary?

You could try that. Everything else being equal you probably want to land on the low end of your range, so that you'll have room to grow within it.

But HR will review the job description and whatever range you choose to ascribe to the new job. They will then check against industry standards for reasonableness and correct it as needed. Remember, this won't likely just be "invented" data. HR won't just be considering you and your new role, but defining the role for the company going forward.

If the job tree has levels of 0-2 and 3-5, then you may be slotting yourself correctly. But if it has levels of 0-3 and 4-8 for comparable positions in your domain, then you may not get away with a set of artificial boundaries.

You could talk with HR and get their assistance. That could help it sail through more quickly. That, plus the backing of your manager might get you what you want.